# How can I set React SEO depend on regional

Tags: reactjs, seo

I want to show seo description depend on regional

If i search my site in google.kr

my site's description will show korean.

If i search my site in google.uk or google.en

my site's description will show English.

Is there any opton I can set seo depend on regional ?

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.40",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
}
```

here is my package.json

```
<Wrapper>
        <MetaTag />
          <Routes>
            {/* Main */}
            <Route element={<CustomRouter isLoggedIn={getCookie('access_token')} />}>
              <Route path="/app/team/*" element={<Dashboard />}/>
              <Route path="/app/user/settings/*" element={<SettingUser />}/>
              <Route path="/app/team/settings/*" element={<SettingTeam />}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path={`/`} element={<Home />} />
            {/* Service */}
            <Route path={`/service/slack`} element={<Slack />} />
            <Route path="/service/dooray" element={<Dooray />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            {/* Auth */}
            <Route path="/app/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
            <Route path="/app/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/app/password/reset" element={<PwdReset />} />
            {/* policies */}
            <Route path="/policies/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
            <Route path="/policies/terms" element={<Terms />} />
            {/* teams */}
            <Route path="/teams/new/*" element={<NewTeam />} />
            <Route path="/teams/new/channel" element={<SelectChannel />} />
            <Route path="/teams/new/link" element={<Link />} />
            {/* not found */}
            <Route path="*" element={<>NOT FOUND</>} />
          </Routes>
      </Wrapper>
```

Here is my router.

sorry for late update.

Comment: Where is the code for your router?  What URLs have you defined for content from different languages?  You need to have different URLs for each language.  See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: I'm sorry. I update the question now. I can't define content from different languages. I use i18n. when user clicks button to change language ( kor and eng are only options ), site's language changed.

Comment: I dont have more html file for each language

Comment: Having just two languages is fine, but you need to created different URLs for different languages.  Clicking the button to change the language needs to change the URL.  If you don't have different URLs, search engines won't be able to see and index your content in multiple languages.  The language MUST be in the URL for SEO.

Comment: If I add language in the URL, what do I have to do for SEO?

Comment: I add /en URL only use one domain. 'www.test.com/en' is my english site. 'www.test.com' is my korea site.